# Is there a way I can rotate the display of my monitor?

Tags: windows-8.1, display, asus-laptop, intel-graphics, orientation

I have a monitor I would like to rotate.  There is no option to do it in the display menu.

[image: http://oi64.tinypic.com/2rgi8mf.jpg]

When I was looking here once there was an option but it was greyed out

[image: http://oi68.tinypic.com/xriac.jpg]

I have an Intel (R) HD Graphics 4000.

This menu appeared when I went into Intel graphics properties.

It looks like I can't post more images.  The option to rotate is not open when I am in the HD Graphics Control panel.

I downloaded the updated drivers from Intel although when I tried to install them it said they were not validated for this computer.

Googling that brought a lot of results from other people with the same issue. It seems the manufacturer can put weird drivers on your computer and prevent you from installing other ones. I tried to manually install them and it didn't work. I would think that they wouldn't need to prevent someone from rotating the monitor but I don't know.

---

I am running Microsoft's Windows version 8.1 64bit.

This is an ASUS laptop.  The product number was on a sticker but it has worn off.  Hold on, I found a file that has the info in it.  It is S200E.

Another site had some suggestions that did not work for the computer I use.

A few more things I tried that did not work

On another page I found the following instructions:

> Holy crap, I got it to work! I'm not a tech guy, but I've been frustrated with this for a year and a half now so I decided to risk it and went to the registry
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318\0001
>
> and changed all of the following values from 0 to 1(after backing the registry up)
>
> Display1_EnableIndependentRotation
>   Display1_IndependentRotation
>   Display1_PortraitMode
>   Display1_RotationCaps
>   Display2_PortraitMode
>   Display2_RotationCaps
>
> I don't know if all of these were necessary but it works now.
>   The method described there did not work for this computer.

The next reply said this:

> I followed ndHP's suggestion about the registers but I also had to change a few more before it worked:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318\0001
>
> Display1_EnableIndependentRotation =1
>
> Display1_IndependentRotation =1
>
> Display1_PortraitMode =1
>
> Display1_RotationCaps =1
>
> Display2_PortraitMode =1
>
> Display2_RotationCaps =1
>
> After doing the changes he suggested I was able to see the option for "Orientation" on the windows display settings but I wasn't able to save the changes.
>
> Then I changed:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318\0001
>
> Display1_DisableAsyncFlips = 0 (was 1)
>
> Display1_RotationCaps = 7
>
> Display2_RotationCaps = 7
>
> VICTORY! Thank you all for your help in this area!
>   Again, doing that did not work for me.

Oddly enough, my Display_RotationCaps were 7 to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + Alt + (Left Arrow, Right arrow, Up Arrow, Down Arrow)

on windows 7 or 10, it will rotate the active screen.

Comment: This does not work for all graphics cards.

Comment: Isn't it a windows feature? It has worked on every computer I've tried it on...If some GPU drivers don't allow it, those would be considered edge cases. I'm running a gtx970 with up to date drivers and it works. ALso works on my laptop that only has integrated graphics. My thought is because its a windows feature, it should work on every updated microsoft based pc.

Comment: I'm not sure. I just know that it only works on some of my PCs.

Comment: Those commands made no change.

Comment: Microsoft puts features like this in the drivers, so things may very depending on hardware. Not because of the hardware, but because of what extra stuff is in the drivers. It has no business being anywhere in the kernel, but dave cutler lost that argument over 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Intel Graphics Control Panel. You can find the display settings there. Relevant link explaining this: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005491.html

The keyboard shortcut might not work, so you can use the Start Menu to find what you're looking for.

Comment: What was posted in the link above was unhelpful because that option does not exist

http://i67.tinypic.com/6thj5s.png

Comment: This seems to be a manufacturer-specific question. Could you post the model and manufacturer of your computer in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should work on your computer:

1. Download [Display](http://noeld.com/programs.asp#Display).
2. Extract the `Display.exe` to a location of your choice (e.g., `C:\Display.exe`).
3. Use the `[right-click] -> New -> Shortcut` dialogue to create shortcuts for the desired orientations:

   ```
   C:\Display.exe /rotate:0
   C:\Display.exe /rotate:90
   C:\Display.exe /rotate:180
   C:\Display.exe /rotate:270
   ```
4. (optional) In each shortcut's properties, you can specify a `Shortcut Key`.